# I am new to using mysql - as i was trying to create a table i got the error below

Tags: python, mysql, sql, create-table

its giving me the error -

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(100) NOT NULL,\n
> Title varchar(100) NOT NULL, Firstname varchar...' at line 1")

```
 con=pymysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", password = "",database ="project1v2")
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (Employeeid int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,Emp ID varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            Title varchar(100) NOT NULL, Firstname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            Middlename varchar(100) NOT NULL,Lastname varchar(100) NOT NULL,Dob varchar(100) NOT NULL,Nationality varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            ni varchar(100) NOT NULL,Addres varchar(100) NOT NULL,Postcode varchar(100) NOT NULL,phonenumber varchar(100) NOT NULL,Email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            Wage varchar(100) NOT NULL,Passportnumber varchar(100) NOT NULL,Passportexpirydate varchar(100) NOT NULL,gender varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            righttowork varchar(100) NOT NULL,Kinname varchar(100) NOT NULL,Kinrelation varchar(100) NOT NULL,Kinadress varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            Kinphonenumber varchar(100) NOT NULL,Kinemail varchar(100) NOT NULL,Username varchar(100) NOT NULL, Passwor varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            accesslevel varchar(100) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (Employeeid)""")
            con.commit()
            con.close()
```

Comment: Check that your command works with a SQL client, it literally says it is a syntax error.

Comment: Great, people spend effort and time to come up with answers and suggestions and then you delete your question... I suggest you spend a bit more time to learn the basics of python before delving into gui's and databases....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not give space to the column name and is you wish to than you must wrap it in the quotes.

```
`emp id`
```

Also you are missing right parenthesis at the end.

```
.. NULL,PRIMARY KEY (Employeeid) ) -- this is missing
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13ff39a33e3cbdc921a9610cca39be96)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Emp ID varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```

Spaces are not allowed in identifiers, unless the identifier is quoted.

I would recommend:

```
EmpID varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```

If you really want that space:

```
`Emp ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```

I would not recommend using such identifier though; you will need to quote it *every time* you use it, which can quickly get tedious.

Comment: thanks for the response but i now have the error - pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8")

Comment: @khaleeq: there is a missing closing parenthese at the end of the statement.